# How to save a database entry only twice per month on each id in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a program using CodeIgniter. I want save a entry in database only twice every month on each id.

```
function save_task() {

    $project_id = $this->input->post('project_id');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $this->init_project_permission_checker($project_id);

    if ($id) {
        if (!$this->can_edit_tasks()) {
            redirect("forbidden");
        }
    } else {
        if (!$this->can_create_tasks()) {
            redirect("forbidden");
        }
    }



    $route_length = $this->input->post('route_length');
    $fuel_milage = $this->input->post('fuel_milage');
    $daily_consumption = $route_length / $fuel_milage;
    $monthly_allowance = $daily_consumption * 26;
    $title = $monthly_allowance / 2;


    $data = array(
        "route_length" => $this->input->post('route_length'),
        "fuel_milage" => $this->input->post('fuel_milage'),
        "daily_consumption" => $route_length / $fuel_milage, 
        "monthly_allowance" => $daily_consumption * 26,
        "title" => $monthly_allowance / 2,
        "description" => $this->input->post('description'),
        "project_id" => $project_id,


        "status" => $this->input->post('status'),


                );
       $reissue_date = time() + (13*24*60*60);

       $data['deadline'] = date('Y-m-d',$reissue_date);

       $data['start_date'] = get_current_utc_time();

    //clint can't save the assign to and collaborators


    $save_id = $this->Tasks_model->save($data, $id);
    if ($save_id) {

        if ($id) {
            //updated
            log_notification("project_task_updated", array("project_id" => $project_id, "task_id" => $save_id, "activity_log_id" => get_array_value($data, "activity_log_id")));
        } else {
            //created
            log_notification("project_task_created", array("project_id" => $project_id, "task_id" => $save_id));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "data" => $this->_task_row_data($save_id), 'id' => $save_id, 'message' => lang('record_saved')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, 'message' => lang('error_occurred')));
    }
}
```

How can I do that ? With each data id I can save only 2 post within 30 days, if I try to insert more than twice it deny to save.

Comment: i would imagine you will have to do a select first, to check the id\date before deciding to do the post

Comment: how ? example code

Comment: I want restriction on project_id, means if I save data on project_id=4 by today then on same project id I should be able to save only after 15 days

Comment: You can save the current entry date and time in the DB table. Then before next insertion of data, you can check whether the previous entry made before 15 days or not.

Comment: current entry date I save, but no idea how to check before next insertion

Comment: i dont know CI specific code. so i cant give you code

Comment: You will need to save the timestamp of each save. If you were allowing the user to save once per month you would just need to store the timestamp of the last save, but since you are allowing them two saves, you will need to store the last two saves. You can do this in your current model, but that will be awkward as you will need two columns (`save_time_1` and `save_time_2`) and then when a new save happens, shift the second timestamp to the first and then store the new timestamp in 2. It would probably be better (easier) to have another model?